# flat file blog engine powered by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, flat-file, blog-engine

Regarding blog engines, are there any blog engines that meet all of the following criteria?

1. exists in the asp.net ecosystem
2. flat file
3. option to edit files as raw html (not markdown)
4. actively maintained project

I have come across [AtomSite](http://atomsite.net/) and [DasBlog](http://dasblog.codeplex.com/), but these projects do not 
seem particularly active.

Answer (score 1):

The number of options in ASP.NET seems limited, and the closest option I have come across so far is [BlogEngine.NET](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/).

**Update 4/16/2014**
[MiniBlog](https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog) could be the way to go. (Hanselman writes about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringASPNETWebPagesAFullyfeaturedMiniBlogUsingJustRazor.aspx).)